# Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting to test c++ projects

Tags: c++, unit-testing

Can I use Microsoft::VisualStudio::TestTools::UnitTesting to test C++ code?
I mean I already have an existing C++ project which doesn't use .NET.

Now I want to write unit tests to test this code.

Can I use UnitTesting framework from Microsoft to test this native Cpp code?

Thanks a lot

Best Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 1):

Yes but with some more additions

1. You need to include the `"CppUnitTest.h"` ofcourse
2. Update the linker directories to include `$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\lib`
3. Update the include paths to include `$(VCInstallDir)UnitTest\include`

Hope that helps